# How to return record which I create in the same query/or created earlier

Tags: php, mysql

How I can return record which I create in the same query.

I tried `$row[Password]` but it doesn't work. Please help

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM characters WHERE GUID=:GUID";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':GUID', $_GET['GUID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindColumn(4, $charactername);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->fetchColumn();
if($res == 1) {
    echo "Already created";
}


if(!$res){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO characters (GUID,Charactername,Password) VALUES (:GUID,:Charactername,FLOOR( 1000 + ( RAND( ) *8999 ) ))";
        $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':GUID', $_GET['GUID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Charactername', $_GET['Charactername'], PDO::PARAM_INT);                 
        $stmt->execute();
        echo " THIS password created with FLOOR";
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to get the record that you are inserting here without an additional select statement?

Comment: You dont have a `$row` variable? So where did that come from

Comment: Regarding to your explanations, I think you have to generate your random content via PHP and pass it to your DB.

Comment: Its not possible

Comment: you know the values already, you just need the [inserted id](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Comment: there is ssense puting all the code? 
check again

Comment: Why are you generating randon paswords?

Comment: @RiggsFolly You should not worry about it because it is not the content of the question.

Comment: If you have to send the password back to the user to view and remember then it is definitely not a security feature

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm sending it back in localhost area to server.Then server in game sends it to player.Its something likr PIN to able player to register his account on www page.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `$stmt->lastInsertId();` after the `$stmt->execute();` to get the inserted record ID and then make another query to select the record.

Comment: But I know which Password I want get because GUID/ID is in url. Now I do like but it doesnt work      $sql = "SELECT Password FROM characters WHERE GUID=:GUID";
       echo "id: " . $row["Password"]."";

Comment: Why do you generate password with the database methods? do it with the php! $password = floor(1000 + mt_rand() * 8999));

Answer (score 0):

You could return the last inserted id by `$id = $stmt->lastInsertId();` after the execute and then perform a select on the id that was returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the random generated password, you may use multiple queries:

```
<?php

$_GET['GUID'] = 1;
$_GET['Charactername'] = 'test';
$sql = "SET @password := FLOOR( 1000 + ( RAND( ) *8999 ));
        INSERT INTO characters (GUID,Charactername,Password) VALUES (:GUID,:Charactername,@password);
        SELECT @password as Password";

$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':GUID', $_GET['GUID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':Charactername', $_GET['Charactername'], PDO::PARAM_STR);                 
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    do {
        if ($rowset = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo " THIS password created with FLOOR: " . $rowset['Password'];
        }
    } while ($stmt->nextRowset());
}
```

If you want all the values inserted from your last statement, you can also use LAST_INSERT_ID():

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO characters (GUID,Charactername,Password) VALUES (:GUID,:Charactername,FLOOR( 1000 + ( RAND( ) *8999 ) ));
        SELECT * FROM characters WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()";

$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':GUID', $_GET['GUID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':Charactername', $_GET['Charactername'], PDO::PARAM_STR);                 
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    do {
        if ($rowset = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo " THIS password created with FLOOR: " . $rowset['Password'];
        }
    } while ($stmt->nextRowset());
}
```